# FParsec parse expressions with parentheses

Tags: parsing, compilation, f#, functional-programming, fparsec

I'm coding my first parser. It's in F# and I'm using with FParsec.

My parser parses things like `true and false`, `(true and false or true)`, `true`, `(((true and false or true)))` etc, which is correct.

But it doesn't parses when it's like `(true and false) or true`. It fails when there are parentheses in the middle of the text.

How can I solve it?

Sample code:

```
let private infixOperator (opp: OperatorPrecedenceParser<_,_,_>) op prec map =
    opp.AddOperator(InfixOperator (op, ws, prec, Associativity.Left, map))

let private oppLogic = new OperatorPrecedenceParser<_,_,_>()

infixOperator oppLogic "is" 1 (fun x y -> Comparison (x, Equal, y))
infixOperator oppLogic "isnt" 1 (fun x y -> Comparison (x, NotEqual, y))
infixOperator oppLogic "or" 2 (fun x y -> Logic (x, Or, y))
infixOperator oppLogic "and" 3 (fun x y -> Logic (x, And, y))

let private exprParserLogic = oppLogic.ExpressionParser

let private betweenParentheses p =
    between (str "(") (str ")") p

oppLogic.TermParser <- choice [
    betweenParentheses exprParserLogic
    pboolean
]

let pexpression =
    choice [
        attempt <| betweenParentheses exprParserLogic
        exprParserLogic
    ]

let private pline =
    ws
    >>. pexpression
    .>> eof
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens for an input like "(true and false) or true" is that `pline` applies, which `pexpression` tries to apply `betweenParentheses exprParserLogic`. This succeeds and parses "(true and false)". So since the parse was successful, it never tries the second option `exprParserLogic` and simply returns to `pline`. `pline` then applies `eof`, which fails because "or true" is still left in the input.

Since `betweenParentheses exprParserLogic` is already part of the operator parser's term parser, there's no reason for you to try to parse it in its own rule. You can just have `pline` invoke `exprParserLogic` and remove `pexpression` altogether (or define `let pexpression = oppLogic.ExpressionParser` and remove `exprParserLogic`). This will correctly parse "(true and false) or true".